# About the conditional probability of sum of random variable $X_i$

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory

> I have a question about conditional probability. For $X_, \cdots, X_n$ be i.i.d Bernoulli random variable with $X_{i}$ having parameter $p_i$.

I know that $$\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=1| X_1+\cdots+X_k=j)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=1, X_1+\cdots+X_k=j)}{\mathbb{P}(X_1+\cdots+X_k=j)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1+\cdots+X_{k-1}=j-1)\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=1)}{\mathbb{P}(X_1+\cdots+X_k=j)}$$

But why
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1+\cdots+X_k=j|X_{k}=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_1+\cdots+X_k=j-1)$$ but not $\mathbb{P}(X_1+\cdots+X_k=j|X_{k}=1)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1+\cdots+X_{k-1}=j-1)}{\mathbb{P}(X_k=1)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition

$$
\mathbb{P}(X_1+...+X_k=j|X_k=1)=\frac{\mathbb{P}((X_1+...+X_{k-1}=j-1)\cap(X_k=1) )}{\mathbb{P}(X_k=1)}
$$
Applying independence,
$$
\mathbb{P}((X_1+...+X_{k-1}=j-1)\cap(X_k=1))=\mathbb{P}(X_1+...+X_{k-1}=j-1)\mathbb{P}(X_k=1),
$$
so the $\mathbb{P}(X_k=1)$ terms in numerator and denominator cancel.